# Adding values to an array in a file and saving it

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, ajax

I have made a site with something like a gallery, and the pictures in it are grouped in different tabs. Each picture has a name and each tab also has one. The main php looks something like this:

```
<?php
 // Tab links generated from $tabs array
 for($i = 1; $i <= count($tabs); $i++)
  {
   echo
   '<li'.(($i == 1)?' class="active"':'').'><a href="#tab'.$i.'">'.$tabs[$i].'</a></li>'."\r\n";
  }
 ?>
 </ul>

 <div class="tab-content">

 <?php
 for($i = 1; $i <= count($tabs); $i++)
  {
  // For each item from $tabs generates corresponding $tab
   echo
   '<div id="tab'.$i.'">
   <div class="thumbs">';
   foreach ( ${'tab'.$i} as $name)
    {
     echo
     '<div class="thumb"'.(($i == 1)?' class="tab active"':'').'>
     <img src="images/thumbs/'.$name.'.jpg">
     <span '.((strlen($name) >= 17)?'id="small" ':'').'class="title"><span>'.$name.'</span></span></a>
     </div>';
    }
   echo
   '</div></div>';
  }
 ?>
```

I have a separate file, that stores the arrays with the values.
It looks like this:

```
$tabs = array(1 => 'Animals', 'Indoors', 'Nature');

$tab1 = array('my dog', 'cat', 'monkey', 'turtoise');
$tab2 = array('wardrobe', 'chair', 'table', 'tv', 'lamp');
```

I want to be able to add elements to the arrays through a input box that's in my website and save the changes in the arrays file. Please assist!

Comment: better plan, start using a data base

Comment: I would not recommend creating PHP files with PHP files. Use a database or save a JSON file and edit that file instead. And you've already tagged MySQL, do you know how to create tables and connect via PHP to your database?

Comment: Use a database. If you can't, use SQLite. Use JSON files. Use XML. Use **anything but plain PHP files**. This approach you're advocating here will lead to nothing but immediate trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to save array to the file

simple use file_put_contents method of php and you may use different argument to save data like FILE_APPEND to add data at last of file

below simple example

```
$dats = "\$db['" .$some_dynamic_code_here ."'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'test here',
    'use_variable'=>'".$variable_need_to_define."'


);" ; 

        file_put_contents('file_path', $dats, FILE_APPEND);
```